# DataReader UTF-8

Tags: c#, formularios

Problema Rapido:
Tengo una `DropDownList` que contiene datos con diferentes caracteres especiales (',´,ç...) y tengo que pasarle el `DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text` a un `OracleComand cmd` para asi luego pasarle el `cmd` al `OracleDataReader dr`.
El problema esta en que el  `dr` no interpreta caracteres especiales, y al ejecutar la consulta esta devuelve 0 `rows` por el echo de que no interpreta los caracteres especiales.

como puedo cambiar el Encode del `dr` para que si que lea dichos caracteres?

Comment: Si estás mostrando de un maestro o algo así ¿no podrías utilizar identificadores para la consulta en lugar de las descripciones?

Comment: Además, sería bueno que pusieses algo de código para que puedan ayudar.

Comment: El codigo es irelevante en este contexto en mi opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente descubrí cual era mi problema:

Estaba utilizando `System.Data.OracleClient` como Libreria de acceso de datos, al cambiarla a `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` Ya funciona. Perdon por haceros perder el tiempo

Comment: Recuerda que también puedes **aceptar tu propia respuesta**, pero debes esperar 48 horas para poder hacerlo. ¡Después de todo, alguien más puede haber propuesto una mejor solución para tu problema! :)

Comment: Bueno, pues al final el código si era relevante :) Bueno me alegro que hayas dado con la solución.

Comment: Gracias a la comunidad por el apoyo :D @Davlio ya contaba con aceptarla, gracias por recordarlo de todas formas :D

Comment: normal hermano, estás aprendiendo y " Perdon por haceros perder el tiempo", nada que ver, aquí estamos para apoyarnos entre todos :D gracias a ti por tener ese espíritu de hacer funcionar las cosas :D lo lograste! que sigan los éxitos en el desarrollo! bendiciones

Answer (score 0):

No debes cambiar el encode del dr, sino el del string que le estás pasando.
Con este código pasarías UTF8 a string unicode. El string final es el que deberías pasarle al dr:

```
var dbEnc = Encoding.UTF8;
var uniEnc = Encoding.Unicode;
byte[] dbBytes = dbEnc.GetBytes(DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text);
byte[] uniBytes = Encoding.Convert(dbEnc, uniEnc, dbBytes);
string mensajeAPasarAlDr = uniEnc.GetString(uniBytes);
```

Comment: De que libreria sacas `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: Ademas, yo tambien se hacer copiapegas de: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381559/utf-8-to-c-sharp-string-from-a-datareader

Comment: Esque ni se ha molestado en cambiar los nombres de las Variables....

Answer (score 0):

Al usar `System.Data.OracleClient` no sé si en la cadena de conexión tenías esto: `Unicode=True`, si es que el problema es de conversión de Unicode a UTF-8. Este valor hace que las llamadas desde el cliente utilice :

> Specifies whether the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle uses UTF16 mode API calls

En [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) se indica que el valor por defecto es `False`.

Aún así, se recomienda usar las librerías cliente de Oracle porque proporcionan mejor rendimiento y porque la librería de MS quedó [obsoleta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7388221/7530407) a partir de .NET 4.0.